# Is there a way to store the value of a pointer but do not access the address?

Tags: c, pointers

Now I create a double pointer to store some words get from a `.txt` document (Since there is no `string` in C language.). I tried to use `fgets` and `fscanf`. When I run `fgets`and `fscanf`for the first time, I can store pointers in double pointers. But when I run it for the second time, I find that the value of the first time is completely overwritten. This is a part of code.

```c
char **out = (char **)malloc(3 * sizeof(char *));
FILE *dictionary = NULL;

dictionary = fopen(filename, "r");

char store[6];

fscanf(dictionary, "%s", store);
printf("%s\n", store);
store[5] = '\n';
out[0] = store;
strcpy(store, "");
fscanf(dictionary, "%s", store);
out[1] = store;
printf("%s\n", out[0]);
printf("%s\n", out[1]);

fclose(dictionary);
return out;
```

The content of txt file is

```
cigar
rebut
sissy
```

My expected result from the code above is

```
cigar
cigar
rebut
```

but the exact output from the code above is

```
cigar
rebut
rebut
```

I just tried to store their values one by one, but it seems to tamper with my previous values as well. I've replaced pointers with arrays, but this keeps showing up. What do I need to pay attention to? Or is there a better alternative?

Comment: Your real container is ```store``` ans it seems to stay in the stack and after ```return``` it is "released" ...

Comment: `store[5] = '\n';` This is last element in that array. You still need a terminating 0 byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you need to allocate memory again for every 1D character array `out[0] = (char*)malloc(5 * sizeof(char));` and use `strcpy`, so the below is the corrected code.

```
char **out = (char **)malloc(3 * sizeof(char *));
FILE *dictionary = NULL;

dictionary = fopen(filename, "r");

char store[6];

out[0] = (char*)malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
fscanf(dictionary, "%s", store);
printf("%s\n", store);
strcpy(out[0], store);

out[1] = (char*)malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
fscanf(dictionary, "%s", store);
strcpy(out[1], store);
printf("%s\n", out[0]);
printf("%s\n", out[1]);

fclose(dictionary);

return 0;
```